# String matching program

Tags: java

I am trying to make a java program to reverse the given string and each time iterate, compare with the reversed string then to print pass if matched else fail.

My program is:

```
package sss;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ssi {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String original,reverse="";
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int ascii11,ascii12,ascii13,ascii14;
        System.out.println("enter the string to be reversed");
        original=sc.next();
        int length=original.length();
        for(int i=length-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            reverse=reverse+original.charAt(i);
        }
        System.out.println(reverse);
        //System.out.println(original);
        for(int j=0;j<original.length()-1;j++)
        {
            ascii11=original.charAt(j);
            ascii12=original.charAt(j+1);
            ascii13=reverse.charAt(j);
            ascii14=reverse.charAt(j+1);
            if(Math.abs(ascii11-ascii12) == Math.abs(ascii13-ascii14))
            {

                System.out.println("pass");

            }
            else 
            {

                System.out.println("fail");
            }   
        }

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

here each time when the for loop iterates i am getting pass or fail for each pair of numbers but i want the o/p as to print only pass or fail ONCE.

can any one help me out please...

Comment: So the code that needs to print out pass or fail shouldn't be in the loop. Why is it in the loop? As a hint, you might want to think about putting it in a separate method - then as soon as you know the overall result, you can return that result.

Comment: Use a flag , make it 0 if fail.Check flag outside the loop.If its's 0, its fail else pass.

Answer (score 1):

**Example Code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PalindromeChecker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String original;        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the string to be reversed: ");
        original = sc.next();

        int halfLength = original.length()/2;
        int lastIndex = original.length() - 1;

        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < halfLength; i++) {
            if(original.charAt(i) != original.charAt(lastIndex - i)) {
                System.out.println("Fail!");
                break;
            }
        }

        // Managed to match all characters
        if(i == halfLength) {
            System.out.println("Pass!");
        }

        sc.close();
    }
}
```

**Input/Output:**

```
Enter the string to be reversed: banana
Fail!
Enter the string to be reversed: RADAR
Pass!
Enter the string to be reversed: asdwwdsa
Pass!
```

So the idea is to:

- Compare the first half of the string with the second half of the string
- Compare the first character with the last character
- Compare the 2nd character with the 2nd last character, and so on.
- If any character does not match, print Fail!
- If the loop finishes, it implies that the string is a [palindrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome) (original == reversed), print Pass!

Comment: The class naming convention ?

Comment: @joeyrohan I can rename it if it bothers you that much

Comment: Not at all.Was just curious to know if it meant something specific.No criticism .

Comment: can u plz tell me how to sort it acc to my program .

Comment: @shreya What do you mean by that? Have you tried the code provided in the answer?

Comment: @shreya You could just replace your entire main function with this

Comment: @shreya If it works, you could accept it as the answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your print statement is inside the loop , so its printing "pass" or "fail" for each loop. You should use a flag to check whether all the ascii characters are same. and then check the status of flag outside the loop.
**OR**
Use StringBuffer it has a built-in method to reverse string.

```
StringBuffer input = new StringBuffer("Your String to reverse");
String reverse = input.reverse().toString();
if(input.equals(reverse))
    System.out.println("pass");
else
    System.out.println("fail");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to flag each comparison of the original and reversed characters with either a pass or a fail boolean value. Obviously if any of them are flagged with a fail, you can then terminate the algorithm and print fail. If the for loop continues with a pass right to the end, then print pass once outside of the for loop.

Comment: how to flag the comparision?

Comment: Use a boolean value like `boolean success`. Set it to false at the start of your program since you don't know if it is a success just yet. Then in your loop set it to either true or false for that given character.

Answer (score -1):

Move your `if` condition out of `for` loop.

```
for(int j=0;j<original.length()-1;j++)
{
    ascii11=original.charAt(j);
    ascii12=original.charAt(j+1);
    ascii13=reverse.charAt(j);
    ascii14=reverse.charAt(j+1);

}

if(Math.abs(ascii11-ascii12) == Math.abs(ascii13-ascii14))
{

    System.out.println("pass");

}
else 
{
    System.out.println("fail");
}
```

Comment: Now it only cares about the last iteration of the loop, which I suspect isn't the desired result.

Comment: as i initialised the variables lyk ascii1,.... locally i get an error if i move my if condition out of for loop.

Comment: @shreya you can initialize your variables with 0.