# IndexOutOfBoundsException when performing string reversals

Tags: java

print the 3 names and reverse them,each has to perform the function as specified below:

diff of pairs should be same.

eg: abxy reverse is yxba, (a-b)=(y-x) similarly bx=xb,xy=ab.
And print ok if all diff matches else print not ok.

```
package sss;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ssi {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String original, reverse = "";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ascii11, ascii12, ascii13, ascii14;
        int a[] = new int[3];
        ArrayList<Integer> ar = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        System.out.println("enter the 3 strings");  
        for(int t = 0; t < a.length; t++) {             
            original = sc.next();           
            int length = original.length();

            for(int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);         
                System.out.println(reverse);

                for(int j = 0; j < original.length() - 1; j++) {
                    ascii11 = original.charAt(j);
                    ascii12 = original.charAt(j + 1);
                    ascii13 = reverse.charAt(j);
                    ascii14 = reverse.charAt(j + 1);

                    if (Math.abs(ascii11 - ascii12) == Math.abs(ascii13 - ascii14)) {           
                        ar.add(0);          
                    } else {
                        ar.add(1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (ar.contains(1)) {
            System.out.println("pass");
        } else {
            System.out.println("fail");
        }

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       sc.close();
    }
}
```

Here is the exception I am getting:

> ```
> enter the 3 strings
> abxy
> y
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
>     at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
>     at sss.ssi.main(ssi.java:37)
> ```

Comment: can any one help me out plz..

Comment: How is this question different from [what you asked a few hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31579481/string-matching-program)? There were a few answers to that, and you haven't actually accepted any.

Comment: here i am getting exception if i add 3 strings

Comment: Learn how to ask a question properly, or go figure it out by yourself. How is "(a-b)=(y-x)" and "bx=xb,xy=ab"? So you are getting an exception? What exception EXACTLY? Provide the stacktrace?

Comment: if i could ,i would have done it any better as i couldnt i just posted it here

Comment: In what way is this not working? You say you're getting an exception, but you don't say what the exception is. Use the edit button to add in the missing information, rather than adding comments.

Comment: and my problem statement says, if i take a string abxy, reverse the string itl be yxba , nw comparing the difference of original string and the reversed one i.e, (a-x) of the original string should be equal to (x-y) i.e the difference of both will be 1 in the same way (x-b)=(b-x) and (x-y)=(b-a). if after calculation the differences are equal den print ok else not ok.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you've got an [`IndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) because on the first iteration of all your loops you have the following state:

- `t` is `0` and `i` is `3`
- `original` is `"abxy"`
- `reverse` is `"y"` (As confirmed by the print statement)
- `j` is `0`

Therefore when you do `reverse.charAt(j + 1)` (Line 37 of `ssi.java`, as shown in the parentheses of the stack trace), you're going to fail, because `reverse` contains only a single character (with index `0`), and `j + 1 == 1`. [As outlined in the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-), the index has to be less than the length:

> **Throws:**
>   IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index argument is negative or not less than the length of this string.

Comment: so what should be my for loop can u plz tell me.

Comment: @shreya I'm not sure I fully understand what the problem you're trying to solve is, and even if I did I'm reluctant to just write code for other people as an answer, as that does nothing to help anyone. Hopefully you understand the problem you were experiencing now and can adapt your algorithm accordingly.